# is there a way for AWS ALB to handle errors silently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

is there a feature in AWS ALB to handle errors silently? so for example, if an error occurs in server_one it will try server_two immediately without letting the end user know that the first request failed in server_one

Comment: No, there is no such feature.

Comment: I'd expect you to typically need some application-level knowledge to know how to retry a particular API call, and even whether or not it's safe to retry.